# When is the metric on a Fréchet space homogeneous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $(F,d)$ be a Fréchet space over $\mathbb{F}\in \{\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}\}$.  Are there conditions under which, there exists some $C,d>0$ such that: for every $f\in F$ and every $k\in \mathbb{F}$ it holds that
$$
d(kf,0)\leq C |k|^d \,d(f,0).
$$

---

Clearly, $C=p=1$ is satisfied if and only if $(F,d)$ is *Banach*; i.e. $d$ is a norm.However, what about the general case?

Namely, is there a characterization/description of such spaces known in the literature?

Comment: For $C=1$ and $d=p\in (0,1]$ such spaces are called **$p$-normed** topological vector spaces. Some information is in Köthe's book *Topological Vector Spaces 1*.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Ah, okay; I'll take a look.  Do you know of a typical concrete example of such a space?

Comment: The main examples are $L_p(\mu)$, $0<p<1$.

Comment: @BillJohnson Fair enough (These are the only ones I generated myself also).